# Virtualbox - Windows 7 x64 slow loading

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-8.1, performance

after moving *.vdi files to my new notebook I noticed that it takes long time to boot WIndows 7 x64(on 2 different VM's) on Windows 8.1 x64. That VM's worked perfectly on my home PC on Windows 7 X64 host(another version of VirtualBox). How I can fix this?

Here are the specs:

VirtualBox 4.3.20 r96997

**Guest Windows 7 x64 specs**
CPU: 4 core 100%
Ram: 8GB
Video memory: 256mb
3D accelaration: on
2D accelaration: on
Enable I/O APIC: on
Enable VT-x/AMD-V: on
Enable Nested Paging: on
Enable PAE/NX: off
Enable EFI: off

**My notebook properties:**
Asus G751
CPU: i7 4710HQ
Ram: 24GB DDR3L
GPU: GTX860m
HDD: 2 x 1TB 5400rpm
Host OS: Windows 8.1 x64

P.S. I moved *.vdi files to my notebook and then just created Vms with the same names as on my PC and with the same settings for everything(CPU, RAM, GPU, e.t.c.).

Comment: After you moved the files did you make sure the files were not fragmented?

Comment: No, how can I check that?

Comment: To me it looks like you are currently processor bound (equal or more cores than the host assigned to the guests), try assigning less cores to the VM.  Also, when you create a brand new Win7 VM on the notebook, does it run as expected? What all have you attempted already in trying to rectify this?

Comment: capture a boot trace with xbootmgr: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score -1):

That's normal. Your laptop disks are 5400, and your desktop are probably 7200 RPM

Comment: My desktop HDD also 5400rpm and by "slow" I mean that windows 7 logo animation proceeded very slow(about 10-15 sec), not in normal speed. On my PC its running smoothly.

Comment: In such case check if you install proper videdrivers on host OS. And activate videoacceleration for virtual machine